# Crash in QMetaObject::changeGuard on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: macos, qt, crash, osx-mavericks

One of my customers gets the following crash in my Qt 4.8.5 application on Mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks). Since I am sort of stuck and can't reproduce it: does anybody here have a hint?

Here is the callstack:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtCore                             0x000000010177adfd QMetaObject::changeGuard(QObject**, QObject*) + 509
1   QtGui                              0x000000010197d716 QCursor::handle() const + 566
2   QtGui                              0x00000001019a5638 QMacCocoaAutoReleasePool::~QMacCocoaAutoReleasePool() + 18632
3   QtGui                              0x000000010199a814 QMacInputContext::reset() + 24884
4   com.apple.AppKit                   0x00007fff92775a62 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2819
5   QtGui                              0x000000010199f814 QMacInputContext::reset() + 45364
6   com.apple.AppKit                   0x00007fff925c5a29 -[NSApplication run] + 646
7   QtGui                              0x00000001019aa680 QDesktopWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*) + 13040
8   QtCore                             0x0000000101762af4 QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 68
9   QtCore                             0x0000000101762ea4 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 324
10  QtCore                             0x000000010176558c QCoreApplication::exec() + 188
```

According to the customer the crash happens doesn't happen on a specific action but rather sometime when working with the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track the problem somewhat down. It happens in a specific multi-selection situation in my application, and tweaking a timer value bypasses the crash.

I still don't really know why it crashes at that specific location, but it might just be my application causing the issue. Anyway, solved me for know and probably not relevant for others.

Answer (score 0):

Note that on call stack you have `QDesktopWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)` call directly by event loop. If you read functionality of [QDesktopWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdesktopwidget.html#details) then it should turn out that test scenario is not related to your application directly.

Try operation related to changes of desktop size, maximize some application (not necessary yours) change desktops, minimize/maximize some application, try multiple monitors, move application between monitors, try change screen resolution, and so on.

Compare OS X version, yours and client. Lately apple did something with multiple monitors support.

---

I googled a bit and I found a something suggesting that 10.9.1 may fix this problem. There are lots of topics about this crush so maybe you will find something useful for you.

Comment: the crash happened on a 10.9.1 system, sorry for not mentioning this. I will test the resize. Can you post one of other mentions of the crash (that you found in Google)? I didn't find an identical one.

Comment: I used [this search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=qdesktopwidget::resizeEvent+maveric+osx)

Comment: Thanks. Google indeed shows a couple of crashes with the resize event in the callstack, but unfortunately none of them ends the same way as mine (crash in QMetaObject::changeGuard). Thus they seem to be different crashes.